# Visual Studio - sharing resource files

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

I have multiple projects that have some of the standard dialog boxes the same, and I would like to put these dialogs along with their resources in a separate location, and include these into all of my projects, so I don't have to make changes in all projects every time something is tweaked.

What is the best practice to accomplish such behaviour?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compile them into a separate **resource DLL**, and then modify the code in each of your projects to access the resources from this DLL instead of from the EXE itself.